# Are there infinitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. some $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ is contained in $[k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4},k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Actually, this question comes from a problem in real analysis: show that $\{\tan(n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ contains a bounded subsequence. When I saw this question, it occurred to me that $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $|\tan x|\leq 1$ on the interval $[k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4},k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}]$. So I tried to show that there exist infinitely many $k$'s such that $[k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4},k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}]$ contains a positive integer $n_k$. But so far, I haven't come up with any effective way to crack this problem. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

**Some numerical simulations:**

[image]

Comment: The spread of each interval is simply π2≈1.57. Every interval from the reals with width has at least one and sometimes two integers.

Comment: @nickalh That makes sense. Good for you, nickalh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread of each interval is simply $\frac{\pi}{2}\approx1.57$.  Every interval from the reals with width $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has at least one and sometimes two integers.

Comment: I believe this fully answers the question, but is it long enough to a valid answer?  Hence the duplicate in comments.

Comment: Less is more. Simplicity makes perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!